# In some cases title is not shown

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller

The self.title of the viewController clearly says Feeds

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
...
    PO1(self.title);//Feeds
}
```

Yet, this is the result:

[image]

I can easily fix this with self.navigationItem.title=self.title;

However, I want an explanation why doesn't this work?

Comment: self.navigationItem.title = @"title";

Comment: what does the method `PO1` do?

Comment: Print result. I do not want to fix that by changing self.navigationItem.title

Comment: Where are u setting the title here? PO1 just logs into the console.

Comment: I am not setting the title. I am just showing what the title is. The title is set in storyboard

Comment: Is this view controller push through a action segue or programmatically ? (or maybe its the root)

Comment: which is the architecture? do you have this view controller in a navigation controller, and there is some other container?